# How do I apply style to each category of a list?

Tags: plugins, categories, customization, shortcode, taxonomy

I need to create a simple plugin to show a list of categories inside the body of the post and, as I am new to coding, I searched for the basics and started to make little changes; it looks like this, by now:

```
// [cats]
function catting ( $atts, $content = null ) {
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category_list(  ', ', '', $post->ID  );
 return '<div id="cats" class="catting">' . $categories . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode("cats", "catting");
```

It shows the categories of a post listed simply and I managed to apply some custom styles on it in order to show it as buttons, but the style is being applied to the shortcode as a whole instead of affecting the categories separate and individually.

I am trying to use `foreach` and to change the commas into a blank space between them, but, every time I try something, it breaks the code or it does not change anything at all.

I would like to know the way to apply the style in each category separately and I thank you very much in advance for the help.

Comment: I am trying to achieve a result like [this](http://i.imgur.com/0GmhtX2.png), but I am achieving [this](http://i.imgur.com/iGBgPV7.png) with the model based on `get_the_category_list()` and [this](http://i.imgur.com/Zzv37ya.png) with another model based on `wp_list_categories()`. The style is being appllied via custom CSS.

Comment: The question is partially solved by now and it is looking like [this](http://i.imgur.com/zKvmQWs.png). The problem was around the field of custom CSS: I was not aware about the powerfull functionality of a simple `a`. The residual problem now is related with the commas between the categories as I continued using the initial code, but I will be looking after a solution for that from now on.

Comment: Just exchanged the commas for `$separator = ' '` and the question is perfectly solved.

Comment: [CATAG](https://wordpress.org/plugins/catag/), the plugin made out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code to reflect the `wp_list_categories()` function reference as suggested by @Usce.

This snippet will create an unordered list, remove the "Categories" list title, and add the `li` class with individual category ID so you can target each link in the list.

`function catting ($atts, $content = null) {
 echo '<div id="cats" class="catting">' . wp_list_categories('title_li=','current_category') . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode("cats", "catting");`

Here's some CSS to remove the bullets and margin so it essentially behaves just as your original code but with `li` wrapping your anchors.

The CSS will break the list we've created into a horizontal line. Just remember to modify your CSS to further customize the outcome i.e. adding styles for buttons.

`#cats.catting ul {
        display: inline;
    }
    #cats.catting ul li.cat-item {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}`

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, @Jamerson, for the help.

Your codes really started cleaning up all the undesirable elements of the list.

But, after starting to use `wp_list_categories`, the style is being applied outside the list both with your code and with another one I was elaborating after your tips; before, it was delineating all the categories of the post at once in a line.

I am going to experiment more with the tips in order to understand better what is happening.

Comment: np, @JorgeAmVF. I'm not sure I completely understand your dilemma, but it reads like a matter of targeting CSS elements. I've modified the CSS in my answer which will specifically target the list in question and break it out into a horizontal line. As long as your classes elsewhere are unique the styles should only apply to said list. Also, the anchors wrapped with list tags can further allow for customization.

Comment: Thanks for the support, @Jarmerson, and sorry for the typo. I realized I was not being clear enough and then I tried to illustrate the problem by adding a comment in the initial question with some pictures of what is happening. I agree with you that I may be not aware of something as it was already a challenge to apply the style in a wrong way and I am doing it while I am forcibly trying to learn the matter from the middle. The tries and the tips are helping a lot after all.

Comment: Awesome! I think the WP functions you have in your code are exactly what you want, it's just a matter of CSS. Send me a link and I will put some CSS together for you.

Comment: [This](https://quaestio.org/il-cammino-della-vita/) is the post page in which I am testing the implementation of the feature. I prepared some CSS copying the settings of another feature of the theme I use and it is working via the custom CSS field, but it is probably not targeting the categories of the post properly with the plugin. Its is being addressed solely by #cats.catting and #cats.catting:hover and adjusting multiple parameters. Thank you again!

Comment: I will have to check it out tomorrow or Monday if you're still in need of some insight. LMK ￼

Comment: Thank you a lot, @Jarmerson. You guided me to found a  way by reading more about CSS. The problem is almost solved and I added another comment with details about what I have done. Basically, I turned `#cats.catting` into `#cats.catting a` and respectively. Now I am going to take out the commas between the categories. I thank you very much for the insights and the good will.

Comment: Glad to share. If I answered your question you can accept it. I appreciate it 

Comment: @JorgeAmVF, your site is looking good :)

Comment: Thanks, @Jarmerson!

I still have to improve its speed and I need to learn the ways of divulgation too: I will be probably consulting the community in the next days.

I was developing this plugin in order to make posts simpler and with less information (and I also added a tag cloud function to experiment with).

I sent a vanilla to Wordpress yesterday: as soon as it is approved, I share it with you.

Comment: Hello, @Jarmerson. The plugin is already available; take a look at my last comment on my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yo don't need to write a plugin for that - what you need already exists. Check this link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-categories/
With this plugin you can display categories in any post or page. Of course, maybe you want to write your own plugin, and in that case this link can be helpful.
I hope that this will help you to speed up a process.

Comment: Thank you, @Alex Black, for the help. It will surely help me to understand the environment better and it worths a test.

Answer (score -1):

There is build in wordpress function for that , so you can use wp_list_categories() for that. Please refer [here to learn more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

And after you display them you an do some CSS if you want to display it as buttons.

I hope this helps.

Kind regards,

Usce

Comment: Thank you, @Usce, for the help.

I started to experiment with `wp_list_categories` and to learn something about its parameters, but it is displaying all the categories of the site in a vertical list instead of an horizontal list of the categories related to the post.

I will try a little more to see what I can get.

Comment: You can apply to them display: inline-block CSS or something to get them in horizontal position

Comment: Thanks for the attention, @Usce. The problem is almost solved because the application of the style on the categories individually has been achieved by a correction of a mistake in the custom CSS style. I am just going to learn a little more about the matter and soon it will totally solved. The `display` was already customized in my custom CSS, but the CSS was not well addressed.